# Optimize One Parameter via Line Search and the rest via Nelder-Mead in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a Log Likelihood function with 5 parameters that needs to be maximized. One of the parameters needs to be optimized via line search method, while the other 4 need to be optimized via Nelder-Mead (or other derivative methods). Does anyone know how I would go about doing both?

The only way I can think of executing it right now, is to do it iteratively, one at a time. So optimize the 4 parameters via Nelder-Mead, then keep them constant while I optimize the 5th via Line Search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proposed method (optimize parameters e.g. 2-5, then hold them constant while optimizing parameter 1) won't work. Instead, you should use a *nested* approach: for example, write a function that optimizes over the four 'multi-dimensional' parameters, and do a line search using that function.

Suppose your objective function `f()` takes a vector of 5 parameters, the first of which corresponds to your line-search dimension.

```r
f2 <- function(p_u, ...) {
   res <- optim(par = start0, 
                fn = function(p) f(c(p_u, p)),
                ...)
   res$value
}
optimize(f2, interval = c(lwr, upr), <optim_args>)
```

- FWIW Nelder-Mead is *not* a derivative-based method
- I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "line search"; `optimize` uses *Brent's method* (`?optimize`: "a combination of golden section search and successive parabolic interpolation")
- I think it makes more sense to nest the 4D search within the 1D search, but you could do it in the opposite order
- in this implementation the 4D search starts from the same starting parameters every time. It might make sense (i.e. would be faster and more robust) to use a *continuation method* where we stored the optimized parameters for each value of `p_u`, e.g. in the environment of the `f2()` function, and used the previous starting value each time. (This would depend on how much the `p_u` values identified by Brent's method jumped around; at the beginning of the optimization procedure the continuation method could actually be *worse* than the naive approach, if (e.g.) Brent's method starts by evaluating the function at both ends of the interval ...)